# Help me to find a proof of this theorem about prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

Waclaw Sierpinski mentions in his book, 'Co wiemy a czego nie wiemy o liczbach pierwszych', mentions a theorem I'd like to know a proof for, but unable to find it anywhere.

The theorem is credited to Sherk, and Sierpinski claims it was proven back in 1830.

The theorem is as follows:

Let $p_n$ denote the $n$th prime number. Then if we pick plus or minus sign correctly, we have $p_{2n}=1\pm p_1 \pm p_2\pm\ldots\pm p_{2n-2} + p_{2n-1}$, as well as $p_{2n+1}=1\pm p_1 \pm p_2\pm\ldots\pm p_{2n-2}\pm p_{2n-1}+ 2p_{2n}$.

For example, $13=1+2-3-5+7+11$.

Help me to find a proof of this statement.

Comment: Sierpinski presents his $1952$ published proof in Ch. 3.11 in his book *Elementary Theory of Numbers* (he claims Teuffel's proof  $(1955)$ is similar).

Comment: I'm wondering if there is any result with respect to the uniqueness of the solutions with respect to the $\pm$ signs.

Comment: @StevenClark I think uniqueness is not possible. For instance: $19 = 1-2+3-5+7+11-13+17$. We can change it $19 = 1-2+3+5-7-11+13+17$ . By changing the signs of equally spaced prime pairs, we can obtain infinitely different expressions as n grows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43681369) is what you’re looking for!

Comment: Possibly not since that much more recent $(1987)$ paper claims to prove generalizations so may be more complex (I can only view the front page at the moment so I can't be sure)